# Google appengine maven plugin cannot find goal 'devserver'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I've been trying to run a maven Google appengine plugin code and keep running into issues.

Running `mvn clean install` from the project directory, I get the error `Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:war failed: basedir <path-to-dir>\target\generated-sources\appengine-endpoints does not exist`.
Looking up on Google's AppEngine website and SO, I used
`mvn appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib` to get a zip file in the `\appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF` folder. But running `mvn appengine:devserver` throws a `Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.34:devserver failed.: NoSuchElementException` error.

Any pointers to fix the error is appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to update to at least 1.9.50? and then run mvn appengine:devserver. I do not think 1.9.34 has that command.

Comment: are you sure your project directory is well structured.Make sure you run that command at the root directory of the project

Comment: @otc - I tried with 1.9.54, still the same.
@Lekens - Yes, the project was pushed (to GitHub) at its last working state six months ago before developers changed! I run the `mvn` commands at the folder containing the projects `pom.xml`

Comment: @PdG is this a multi module mvn? if so you might want to get inside the ear folder and run 'mvn appengine:devserver'

Comment: @otc - I'm guessing that it is a single module mvn as I don't see an 'ear' folder.